# Zend: How to nest different controllers into one big?

Tags: zend-framework, controller, nested

What are (the best) approaches for the **Zend Framework** to **nest different controllers actions** into one big one?

And how would I solve the following situation:
A link in my main big view calls an other view where I can select a specific value and come back automatically after selecting to the main view and pre-filling this selected value?

Answer (score 1):

You can run several actions in one shot using the [ActionStack helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) (it's there, a little down).  I'm not sure about your second question.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute additional controller/action combinations in the current controller/action's view by doing something like this:

```
// will execute the headerAction() function of the PageController with the default module
<?= $this->action('header', 'page', 'default') ?>
```

This is what we include in our layouts to render a common header on each page without having to include the prep for that in each controller's action and the layout logic in each layout phtml file. This will work in a regular view as well.